# What is the maximal sparsity of a matrix?

Tags: matrices

Given a $m \times 2m$ matrix G with rank(G)=m, what is the maximal number of zeros in the product $WG$ where $W$ is an $m \times m$ nondegenerate matrix?

An obvious lower bound is $m(m-1)$ and $W$ is given by a matrix that transforms the first $m$ columns of $G$ to a standard basis in $\mathbb{R}^m$. When $m=1$ this lower bound is in fact attained. Is it possible to have more zeros when m>>1?

Comment: What do you mean by "nondegenerate matrix"? Nonsingular?

Answer (score 1):

I expect not.  If I get your question,  you are asking for a basis for R, the row space of G, that
has as many zero coordinates as possible.  I can imagine that there are subspaces of dimension m inside
F^2m for m small with respect to the cardinality of the base field F that avoid bases with more than the minimal
number, but I cannot
at this time provide explicit examples with proof for all n.  Something that should work is having the ith row of
G be e_i concatenated with f_i, where e_i is the canonical ith basis vector with m-1 zeros and one 1,
and f_i is an m vector of values of (x^(i-1) +i) evaluated at x=1 to m, but I have only looked at the case
m=2, where the rows are 1 0 2 2  and  0 1 3 4.  The argument should go something like : if I produce
k zeroes in "the second half" of such a G, I take away k or more zeros in "the first half" because the
coefficients of the polynomial which is generated in the second half will dictate many nonzero entries
in the first half, but I have not done the whole argument myself.

Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2013.01.15

Comment: It may be possible to base a proof on a result (Sturm?) that counts zeros by counting alternations in sign of the coefficients.  Gerhard "Leaving The Fun For Others" Paseman, 2013.01.15